# No matching function for call to 'CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL'

Tags: ios

My target links against the ImageIO framework, and in the file in which I use `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL`, I `#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>`, and yet I still get said error. Any ideas?

Comment: Is ImageIO added as a framework in project->summary?

Answer (score 0):

> CGImageDestination objects, available in OS X v10.4 or later, abstract the
>   data-writing task. An image destination can represent a single image or
>   multiple images. It can contain thumbnail images as well as properties
>   for each image.

[Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImageDestination/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: This documentation shows that this function is defined in `<ImageIO/CGImageDestination.h>`, which is included in `ImageIO/ImageIO.h`. I mentioned in my question that I imported this header.

Comment: Hey run that program with breakpoint ,and let us know the error ,otherwise how can i give answer

Comment: The program doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

The message in the error was `Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'NSURL *' to CFURLRef' (aka qconst __CFURL *) for 1st argument`.

I needed to cast the first argument, which was type `NSURL`, to a `CFURLRef`.